# How to enable vertical Scollbars in a DataGridView when the AllowUserToAddRows property is set to false

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have noticed that the vertical scroll bars appear in the DataGridView only when the `AllowUserToAddRows` property is set to `true`. I have a required where number of rows are fixed and cannot change. When I set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false` and type in multiple lines (>20) in a Cell in the DataGridView, the content gets cut where the main form ends because the vertical scroll bars don't appear.

How can I make it appear provided the `AllowUserToAddRows` is set to `false` in all cases?

Comment: Not sure how you have configured your DGV, but scrollbars appear when `AllowUserToAddRows = false` and you add Rows or the Row is automatically resized when the content of a Cell expands (I assume you have set `Resizable = true` in the RowTemplate).

Comment: Resizable is set to false. The vertical scroll does appear if the collective row height is greater than the height of the data grid, but doesn't appear when there is only one row with a cell having multi-line text and the single row height exceeds the total control height.

Comment: With a single Row, the DGV cannot scroll, since it only scrolls one Row at a time, bringing the previous/next Row to the top line. A single Row is already in that position. You can see the `VerticalScrollingOffset` is read-only. -- When `AllowUserToAddRows = true`, you have two Rows, so it can scroll. You could do the same thing, using a *fake* Row (maybe painted to look like the background).